# Scare off snakes from a weed full land

Tags: drainage, pest-control, shallow

I have just inherited an acre of residential land. The land is full of weeds and some trees. It is 2-3 metres below the road that lies near it. It is as I believe infested with snakes.

How can I scare off the snakes?

Can I dump soil directly above this piece of land? I need to raise its altitude about a metre above the road.

My area is flood infested.

If necessary to mention, I am in the north eastern part of India.

Comment: Would check with local government, because some places have regulations about changing drainage that affects neighbours.  Flood zones also have regulations.  Just dumping dirt in a place that gets flooded, might be washed away, so need to prevent that.

Comment: 14,000 cubic meters of fill, roughly, if you have an average 2.5m below road on an acre and want it 1 meter above the road. That's a whole lot of dump trucks in any part of the planet.

Comment: What permits are required or regulations to follow? Many countries control this sort of thing... Any wildlife that may be protected?

Comment: Raising the whole acre is a lot.  Raising a section to build a house is a lot less, but would probably involve the use of piles driven down into the ground to stabilize the house.  Loose dirt settles quite a bit.

Comment: Just as effective and far less costly to put in the piles and forget the dirt, leaving the house on stilts.

Comment: Upvote for sweet title which sounds to me like a lyric.

Comment: @crip659 I am in Assam. Floods affect us [often](https://www.indiatvnews.com/news/india/assam-flood-people-died-casualties-death-toll-stands-at-190-landslides-latest-news-updates-2022-07-08-790695). Usually, we make [embankment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embankment_(earthworks)). Even then the mighty [Brahmaputra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmaputra_River) and its tributaries hit us hard. So, most of the people dump soil every year to increase the height of their lands. Of course, there are government license for those trucks. We pay about 8 dollars per truck of soil.

Comment: @Ecnerwal yes. Roughly I will need to spend about 3 lakh of Indian rupees to raise the level of my land. It's a project of mine to build a fine home there with fruit trees and flowers. I would love to see birds, and flowers.

Comment: @SolarMike Usually when we catch snakes, we call the forest office. They release the snake in forest areas. I haven't seen any snake but people claim to have seen some snakes. I don't know the number but seems like there would be several. I don't want to kill any snakes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Mow.**

Snakes like tall grass and weeds as you know.  Hire someone with a tractor or riding mower to mow the grass short.  The snakes will leave.  Keep it mowed short.  If the grass stays short they will not come back.

Comment: Given that the area floods regularly, I rather doubt this will affect the snake population significantly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't scare OFF snakes, but if you are scared OF snakes, you can wear [snake-resistant boots](https://www.amazon.in/s?k=snake%20resistant%20boots) whenever you are on your land.

Answer (score 0):

In a word: don't.  What you're suggesting is to take what appears to be excellent buffer-zone land and basically destroy it.  Not only is this unecologicl but most likely will do the reverse of what you want.
If what you are after is ensuring your roadway remains passable, then put in culverts (beneath the roadway, crossing at lowest points in the land) and build up the road, not the land surrounding it.

Answer (score -1):

Most cats love to hunt especially for slithering and other moving creatures. Most cats are more than agile and smart enough to kill and/or eat snakes. They will also go after other small rodents etc. Feed them enough to be healthy but do not overfeed them. This will probably take a few months, do not expect overnight results.

Comment: Or get a herd of mongoose. I hear they're fond of snake, too. Depending on the snakes and the cats, I'm not sure that would be a fair fight for the kitties. (Though, TBH, I'm not really a cat fan, so I wouldn't be bothered).